# 250 users with a data dir on a central server - how would you set it up?

Tags: storage, thin-client, client-server, best-practices

I'd like to get best-practice advice on how to setup a scheme where 250 users or more have OS independent access to their own data-dir / user-dir on a central server in the local network. from the server's perspective:

- Would you set up a big /users dir on the server with subdirs for each user with quota, on one big partition (underlying fat storage, of course)?
- Or would you setup a dedicated partition for each user living in a big ZFS, LVM disk pool?

Dirs would be shared over the network via SAMBA, NFS or probably WebDAV, HBA, aoE - not fully knowing what the latter do to the permission case...

What are the pros and cons of "dedicated partition" vs "permission based shared partition"? What's best practice today?

Comment: Depends how details you want to do in. In my place we've just got a "Staff" Folder with everybody's home dirs in that, although you could have staff/admin, staff/finance, staff/developers, staff/sales, for example, but for 250 users that's probably overkill. This maybe better suited to ServerFault, don't repost it though, the community will decide to migrate or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitions:

Cons: Partition based allocation would be extremely cumbersome in all cases creating new users,deleting and migrating to other machines.

A better solution would be to use nfs with quotas.

Pros: easier to manage , increase allocation etc.

In case you choose to not go with NFS you can have individual home directories in seperate files

eg

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=user-A bs=1024 count=1000000
```

This creates a 1G file user-A which will be used for A's network directory

```
root@x:/tmp# mkfs.ext3 user-A 
mke2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
user-A is not a block special device.
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
```

format

```
root@x:/tmp# mkdir users/user-A

root@x:/tmp# mount user-A users/user-A -o loop
root@x:/tmp# df users/user-A/
```

mount this.

Pros: easier to add/delete users,migrate between disks/servers

Cons: changing size of directories,

Comment: Interesting 3rd way of doing it: all in a file! (didn't think of that). Like a poor-man's partition volume abstraction, simple and elegant! Agreeing that it imposes volume shink/grow admin overhead. And still, I am having a hard time learning that it's good to dedicate a full partition to one user (neglecting all the permission/user mechanisms a filesystem itself offers), compare: http://serverfault.com/a/340583/102280

Comment: I dont think dedicating a partition per user has any tangible benefits .